# Unicode letters with more than 1 alphabetic latin character?

Tags: unicode, character, letters, alphabet, latin

I'm not really sure how to express it but I'm searching for unicode letters which are more than one visual latin letter.

I found this in Word so far:

- Ǳ
- ǲ
- ǳ
- Ǌ
- ǈ
- Ǉ
- ǋ
- ǌ

Any others?

Comment: [Ǆ](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/01c4/index.htm), [ǅ](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/01c5/index.htm) and [ǆ](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/01c6/index.htm) also

Comment: @Lưu Vĩnh Phúc - not really latin characters

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here are some of the characters I've found. I'd first done this manually by looking at some probable blocks. However I've later written a Python script to do this automatically that you can find at the end of this answer

[Digraphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraph_(orthography)#In_Unicode)

| Two Glyphs | Digraph | Unicode Code Point | HTML |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DZ, Dz, dz | Ǳ, ǲ, ǳ | U+01F1 U+01F2 U+01F3 | &#x1F1; &#x1F2; &#x1F3; |
| DŽ, Dž, dž | Ǆ, ǅ, ǆ | U+01C4 U+01C5 U+01C6 | &#x1C4; &#x1C5; &#x1C6; |
| IJ, ij | Ĳ, ĳ | U+0132 U+0133 | &#x132; &#x133; |
| LJ, Lj, lj | Ǉ, ǈ, ǉ | U+01C7 U+01C8 U+01C9 | &#x1C7; &#x1C8; &#x1C9; |
| NJ, Nj, nj | Ǌ, ǋ, ǌ | U+01CA U+01CB U+01CC | &#x1CA; &#x1CB; &#x1CC; |

[Ligatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_ligature#Ligatures_in_Unicode_(Latin_alphabets))

| Non-ligature | Ligature | Unicode | HTML |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AA, aa | Ꜳ, ꜳ | U+A732, U+A733 | &#xA732; &#xA733; |
| AE, ae | Æ, æ | U+00C6, U+00E6 | &AElig; &aelig; |
| AO, ao | Ꜵ, ꜵ | U+A734, U+A735 | &#xA734; &#xA735; |
| AU, au | Ꜷ, ꜷ | U+A736, U+A737 | &#xA736; &#xA737; |
| AV, av | Ꜹ, ꜹ | U+A738, U+A739 | &#xA738; &#xA739; |
| AV, av (with bar) | Ꜻ, ꜻ | U+A73A, U+A73B | &#xA73A; &#xA73B; |
| AY, ay | Ꜽ, ꜽ | U+A73C, U+A73D | &#xA73C; &#xA73D; |
| et |  | U+1F670 | &#x1F670; |
| f‌f | ﬀ | U+FB00 | &#xFB00; |
| f‌f‌i | ﬃ | U+FB03 | &#xFB03; |
| f‌f‌l | ﬄ | U+FB04 | &#xFB04; |
| f‌i | ﬁ | U+FB01 | &#xFB01; |
| f‌l | ﬂ | U+FB02 | &#xFB02; |
| OE, oe | Œ, œ | U+0152, U+0153 | &OElig; &oelig; |
| OO, oo | Ꝏ, ꝏ | U+A74E, U+A74F | &#xA74E; &#xA74F; |
| ſs, ſz | ẞ, ß | U+1E9E, U+00DF | &szlig; |
| st | ﬆ | U+FB06 | &#xFB06; |
| ſt | ﬅ | U+FB05 | &#xFB05; |
| TZ, tz | Ꜩ, ꜩ | U+A728, U+A729 | &#xA728; &#xA729; |
| ue | ᵫ | U+1D6B | &#x1D6B; |
| VY, vy | Ꝡ, ꝡ | U+A760, U+A761 | &#xA760; &#xA761; |

There are a few other ligatures that are used for phonetic transcription but looks like Latin characters

| Non-ligature | Ligature | Unicode | HTML |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| db | ȸ | U+0238 | &#x238; |
| dz | ʣ | U+02A3 | &#x2A3; |
| IJ, ij | Ĳ, ĳ | U+0132, U+0133 | &#x132; &#x133; |
| ls | ʪ | U+02AA | &#x2AA; |
| lz | ʫ | U+02AB | &#x2AB; |
| qp | ȹ | U+0239 | &#x239; |
| ts | ʦ | U+02A6 | &#x2A6; |
| ui | ꭐ | U+AB50 | &#xAB50; |
| turned ui | ꭑ | U+AB51 | &#xAB51; |

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_precomposed_Latin_characters_in_Unicode#Digraphs_and_ligatures

---

## Edit:

There are more [letterlike symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letterlike_Symbols) beside ℻ and ℡ like what the OP found in the comment:

> ℀ ℁ ⅍ ℅ ℆ ℔ ℠ ™

Longer letters are mainly from the [CJK Compatibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_Compatibility) block

| U+XXXX | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| U+338x | ㎀ | ㎁ | ㎂ | ㎃ | ㎄ | ㎅ | ㎆ | ㎇ | ㎈ | ㎉ | ㎊ | ㎋ | ㎌ | ㎍ | ㎎ | ㎏ |
| U+339x | ㎐ | ㎑ | ㎒ | ㎓ | ㎔ | ㎕ | ㎖ | ㎗ | ㎘ | ㎙ | ㎚ | ㎛ | ㎜ | ㎝ | ㎞ | ㎟ |
| U+33Ax | ㎠ | ㎡ | ㎢ | ㎣ | ㎤ | ㎥ | ㎦ | ㎧ | ㎨ | ㎩ | ㎪ | ㎫ | ㎬ | ㎭ | ㎮ | ㎯ |
| U+33Bx | ㎰ | ㎱ | ㎲ | ㎳ | ㎴ | ㎵ | ㎶ | ㎷ | ㎸ | ㎹ | ㎺ | ㎻ | ㎼ | ㎽ | ㎾ | ㎿ |
| U+33Cx | ㏀ | ㏁ | ㏂ | ㏃ | ㏄ | ㏅ | ㏆ | ㏇ | ㏈ | ㏉ | ㏊ | ㏋ | ㏌ | ㏍ | ㏎ | ㏏ |
| U+33Dx | ㏐ | ㏑ | ㏒ | ㏓ | ㏔ | ㏕ | ㏖ | ㏗ | ㏘ | ㏙ | ㏚ | ㏛ | ㏜ | ㏝ | ㏞ | ㏟ |

Among the 3-letter-like symbols are ㎈ ㎑ ㎒ ㎓ ㎔㏒ ㏕ ㏖ ㏙ ㎪ ㎫ ㎬ ㎭ ㏆ ㏿ ㍱... Probably the ones with most characters are ㎉ and ㎯

Unicode even have codepoints for [Roman numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_Forms). Here another 4-letter-like character can be found: Ⅷ

| U+XXXX | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| U+215x | ⅐ | ⅑ | ⅒ | ⅓ | ⅔ | ⅕ | ⅖ | ⅗ | ⅘ | ⅙ | ⅚ | ⅛ | ⅜ | ⅝ | ⅞ | ⅟ |
| U+216x | Ⅰ | Ⅱ | Ⅲ | Ⅳ | Ⅴ | Ⅵ | Ⅶ | Ⅷ | Ⅸ | Ⅹ | Ⅺ | Ⅻ | Ⅼ | Ⅽ | Ⅾ | Ⅿ |
| U+217x | ⅰ | ⅱ | ⅲ | ⅳ | ⅴ | ⅵ | ⅶ | ⅷ | ⅸ | ⅹ | ⅺ | ⅻ | ⅼ | ⅽ | ⅾ | ⅿ |
| U+218x | ↀ | ↁ | ↂ | Ↄ | ↄ | ↅ | ↆ | ↇ | ↈ | ↉ | ↊ | ↋ |  |  |  |  |

If normal numbers can be considered then there are some other code points for multiple digits like ⒆ ⒇ ⓳ ⓴ in [enclosed alphanumerics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enclosed_Alphanumerics)

| U+XXXX | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| U+246x | ① | ② | ③ | ④ | ⑤ | ⑥ | ⑦ | ⑧ | ⑨ | ⑩ | ⑪ | ⑫ | ⑬ | ⑭ | ⑮ | ⑯ |
| U+247x | ⑰ | ⑱ | ⑲ | ⑳ | ⑴ | ⑵ | ⑶ | ⑷ | ⑸ | ⑹ | ⑺ | ⑻ | ⑼ | ⑽ | ⑾ | ⑿ |
| U+248x | ⒀ | ⒁ | ⒂ | ⒃ | ⒄ | ⒅ | ⒆ | ⒇ | ⒈ | ⒉ | ⒊ | ⒋ | ⒌ | ⒍ | ⒎ | ⒏ |
| U+249x | ⒐ | ⒑ | ⒒ | ⒓ | ⒔ | ⒕ | ⒖ | ⒗ | ⒘ | ⒙ | ⒚ | ⒛ | ⒜ | ⒝ | ⒞ | ⒟ |
| U+24Ax | ⒠ | ⒡ | ⒢ | ⒣ | ⒤ | ⒥ | ⒦ | ⒧ | ⒨ | ⒩ | ⒪ | ⒫ | ⒬ | ⒭ | ⒮ | ⒯ |
| U+24Bx | ⒰ | ⒱ | ⒲ | ⒳ | ⒴ | ⒵ | Ⓐ | Ⓑ | Ⓒ | Ⓓ | Ⓔ | Ⓕ | Ⓖ | Ⓗ | Ⓘ | Ⓙ |
| U+24Cx | Ⓚ | Ⓛ | Ⓜ | Ⓝ | Ⓞ | Ⓟ | Ⓠ | Ⓡ | Ⓢ | Ⓣ | Ⓤ | Ⓥ | Ⓦ | Ⓧ | Ⓨ | Ⓩ |
| U+24Dx | ⓐ | ⓑ | ⓒ | ⓓ | ⓔ | ⓕ | ⓖ | ⓗ | ⓘ | ⓙ | ⓚ | ⓛ | ⓜ | ⓝ | ⓞ | ⓟ |
| U+24Ex | ⓠ | ⓡ | ⓢ | ⓣ | ⓤ | ⓥ | ⓦ | ⓧ | ⓨ | ⓩ | ⓪ | ⓫ | ⓬ | ⓭ | ⓮ | ⓯ |
| U+24Fx | ⓰ | ⓱ | ⓲ | ⓳ | ⓴ | ⓵ | ⓶ | ⓷ | ⓸ | ⓹ | ⓺ | ⓻ | ⓼ | ⓽ | ⓾ | ⓿ |

and in [Enclosed Alphanumeric Supplement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enclosed_Alphanumeric_Supplement)

> , , , , , , , , , , , ,

A few more:

[Currency symbol group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currency_Symbols_(Unicode_block))

> ₧ ₨ ₶ ₯ ₠ ₢ ₷

[Miscellaneous technical group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miscellaneous_Technical)

> ⎂ ⏨

[Control pictures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_Pictures) (probably you'll need to zoom out to see)

| U+XXXX | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| U+240x | ␀ | ␁ | ␂ | ␃ | ␄ | ␅ | ␆ | ␇ | ␈ | ␉ | ␊ | ␋ | ␌ | ␍ | ␎ | ␏ |
| U+241x | ␐ | ␑ | ␒ | ␓ | ␔ | ␕ | ␖ | ␗ | ␘ | ␙ | ␚ | ␛ | ␜ | ␝ | ␞ | ␟ |
| U+242x | ␠ | ␡ | ␢ | ␣ | ␤ | ␥ | ␦ |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

[Alchemical Symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alchemical_Symbols_(Unicode_block))

> 

[Musical Symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_Symbols_(Unicode_block))

> 

And there are the emojis   ™

Vertical bars may be considered uppercase i or lowercase L (like your 〷 example which is actually the [TELEGRAPH LINE FEED SEPARATOR SYMBOL](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/3037/index.htm)) and we have

- Vai syllable see ꔖ 0xa516
- Large triple vertical bar operator ⫼ 0x2afc
- Counting rod tens digit three:  0x1d36b
- Suzhou numerals 〢 〣
- Chinese river 川
- ║ BOX DRAWINGS DOUBLE VERTICAL...

---

Here's the automatic script to find the multi-character letters

```py
import unicodedata

for c in range(0, 0x10FFFF + 1):
    d = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', chr(c))
    if len(d) > 1 and d.isascii() and d.isalpha():
        print("U+%04X (%s): %s\n" % (c, chr(c), d))
```

It won't be able to find many ligatures like æ or œ because they're not considered [orthographic ligatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographic_ligature) and aren't decomposable in Unicode. Here's the result in Unicode 11.0.0 (checked with [unicodedata.unidata_version](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.unidata_version))

```
U+0132 (Ĳ): IJ
U+0133 (ĳ): ij
U+01C7 (Ǉ): LJ
U+01C8 (ǈ): Lj
U+01C9 (ǉ): lj
U+01CA (Ǌ): NJ
U+01CB (ǋ): Nj
U+01CC (ǌ): nj
U+01F1 (Ǳ): DZ
U+01F2 (ǲ): Dz
U+01F3 (ǳ): dz
U+20A8 (₨): Rs
U+2116 (№): No
U+2120 (℠): SM
U+2121 (℡): TEL
U+2122 (™): TM
U+213B (℻): FAX
U+2161 (Ⅱ): II
U+2162 (Ⅲ): III
U+2163 (Ⅳ): IV
U+2165 (Ⅵ): VI
U+2166 (Ⅶ): VII
U+2167 (Ⅷ): VIII
U+2168 (Ⅸ): IX
U+216A (Ⅺ): XI
U+216B (Ⅻ): XII
U+2171 (ⅱ): ii
U+2172 (ⅲ): iii
U+2173 (ⅳ): iv
U+2175 (ⅵ): vi
U+2176 (ⅶ): vii
U+2177 (ⅷ): viii
U+2178 (ⅸ): ix
U+217A (ⅺ): xi
U+217B (ⅻ): xii
U+3250 (㉐): PTE
U+32CC (㋌): Hg
U+32CD (㋍): erg
U+32CE (㋎): eV
U+32CF (㋏): LTD
U+3371 (㍱): hPa
U+3372 (㍲): da
U+3373 (㍳): AU
U+3374 (㍴): bar
U+3375 (㍵): oV
U+3376 (㍶): pc
U+3377 (㍷): dm
U+337A (㍺): IU
U+3380 (㎀): pA
U+3381 (㎁): nA
U+3383 (㎃): mA
U+3384 (㎄): kA
U+3385 (㎅): KB
U+3386 (㎆): MB
U+3387 (㎇): GB
U+3388 (㎈): cal
U+3389 (㎉): kcal
U+338A (㎊): pF
U+338B (㎋): nF
U+338E (㎎): mg
U+338F (㎏): kg
U+3390 (㎐): Hz
U+3391 (㎑): kHz
U+3392 (㎒): MHz
U+3393 (㎓): GHz
U+3394 (㎔): THz
U+3396 (㎖): ml
U+3397 (㎗): dl
U+3398 (㎘): kl
U+3399 (㎙): fm
U+339A (㎚): nm
U+339C (㎜): mm
U+339D (㎝): cm
U+339E (㎞): km
U+33A9 (㎩): Pa
U+33AA (㎪): kPa
U+33AB (㎫): MPa
U+33AC (㎬): GPa
U+33AD (㎭): rad
U+33B0 (㎰): ps
U+33B1 (㎱): ns
U+33B3 (㎳): ms
U+33B4 (㎴): pV
U+33B5 (㎵): nV
U+33B7 (㎷): mV
U+33B8 (㎸): kV
U+33B9 (㎹): MV
U+33BA (㎺): pW
U+33BB (㎻): nW
U+33BD (㎽): mW
U+33BE (㎾): kW
U+33BF (㎿): MW
U+33C3 (㏃): Bq
U+33C4 (㏄): cc
U+33C5 (㏅): cd
U+33C8 (㏈): dB
U+33C9 (㏉): Gy
U+33CA (㏊): ha
U+33CB (㏋): HP
U+33CC (㏌): in
U+33CD (㏍): KK
U+33CE (㏎): KM
U+33CF (㏏): kt
U+33D0 (㏐): lm
U+33D1 (㏑): ln
U+33D2 (㏒): log
U+33D3 (㏓): lx
U+33D4 (㏔): mb
U+33D5 (㏕): mil
U+33D6 (㏖): mol
U+33D7 (㏗): PH
U+33D9 (㏙): PPM
U+33DA (㏚): PR
U+33DB (㏛): sr
U+33DC (㏜): Sv
U+33DD (㏝): Wb
U+33FF (㏿): gal
U+FB00 (ﬀ): ff
U+FB01 (ﬁ): fi
U+FB02 (ﬂ): fl
U+FB03 (ﬃ): ffi
U+FB04 (ﬄ): ffl
U+FB05 (ﬅ): st
U+FB06 (ﬆ): st
U+1F12D (): CD
U+1F12E (): WZ
U+1F14A (): HV
U+1F14B (): MV
U+1F14C (): SD
U+1F14D (): SS
U+1F14E (): PPV
U+1F14F (): WC
U+1F16A (): MC
U+1F16B (): MD
U+1F190 (): DJ
```

Comment: Is there even more? Found ℻ and ℡

Comment: And 〷 and ㍴ are also nice. What's the longest latin one?

Comment: @BlackMatrix please see above. It depends on how you define "longest". If it's about character length then probable candidates are ㎉ ㎯ Ⅷ  

Comment: Fantastic. Very nice answer :)